# Unconditional layout inflation from ViewAdapter: Should Use ViewHolder...?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listview-adapter

I have a list view that show ArrayList of Object (Class "Doenca"), and this warning appear in my inflater, i'm use ListView adapter in a Class. See:

```java
public class DoencaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Doenca> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Doenca> doencaArrayList;

    public DoencaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Doenca> doencaArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.linhas_dados_patologia_grupo, doencaArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.doencaArrayList = doencaArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linhas_dados_patologia_grupo, parent, false);

        // Indicando quem é quem no layout XML
        TextView nomeDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaNome);
        TextView causaDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaCausa);
        TextView efeitoDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaEfeito);
        TextView cuidadoDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaCuidados);
        TextView prevencaoDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaPrevencao);
        TextView categoriaDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaCategoria);
        TextView criadorDoenca = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaCriador);
        ImageView doencaFoto = root.findViewById(R.id.doencaFoto);


        // Atribuindo valores a cada doença adicionada pelo usuário
        nomeDoenca.setText(doencaArrayList.get(position).getNome());
        causaDoenca.setText(doencaArrayList.get(position).getCausa());

        efeitoDoenca.setText(doencaArrayList.get(position).getEfeito());



        cuidadoDoenca.setText(doencaArrayList.get(position).getCuidados());
        prevencaoDoenca.setText(doencaArrayList.get(position).getPrevencao());
        categoriaDoenca.setText(doencaArrayList.get(position).getCategoria());

        criadorDoenca.setText(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());

        switch (doencaArrayList.get(position).getCategoria().toString()){
            case "Inflamação":
                doencaFoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_doenca1);
            // listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.preto1)));
                break;
            case "Infecção":
                doencaFoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_doenca2);
            //    listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.amarelo2)));
                break;
            case "Zoonose":
                doencaFoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_doenca3);
           //     listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.vermelho3)));
                break;
            case "Viral":
                doencaFoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_doenca4);
            //   listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.azul4)));
                break;
            case "Outros":
                doencaFoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_doenca5);
                break;
            default:
                doencaFoto.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_doenca5);
            //   listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.laranja5)));
                break;
        }
        return  root;
    }
}
```

I can't see anything error to can will cause this warning. But, the items of my listview showing normally, just one item not showing but it to must be DataBase push data.

Comment: If `convertView` is not null you can use it as `root` instead of inflating the layout.

Comment: What is convertView?

Comment: one of the 3 parameters you get passed for `getView(..)`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you would want to initialize the view because `convertView` can be re-used as views get recycled.

```java
public class DoencaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Doenca> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Doenca> doencaArrayList;

    public DoencaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Doenca> doencaArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.linhas_dados_patologia_grupo, doencaArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.doencaArrayList = doencaArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView != null) {
            view = convertView;
        } else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.linhas_dados_patologia_grupo, parent, false);
        }
        ...
        return view;
    }

}
```

Also, you may want to consider using RecyclerView.

Comment: Thanks, do you think it might interfere with one of my items not being displayed?

I have 6 items, and only one of them is null, I asked another question about it.